# Improving wifi connections in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I have a new laptop now with Ubuntu installed. The wifi at the office is much spottier than it used to be in my old computer. (It sometimes fails to connect, and sometimes drops the connection.) I'm looking for a good setting for iwconfig that would fix it. I don't know what are good parameters for each of the options in iwconfig...

I'm aware that switching off my wifi power management would solve the problem, but I would prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This involves A LOT of trial and error. But things I have played with that help are:

1. Use a program or iwlist to scan for other wireless networks and, if possible, set the frequency/channel of your router to be at least two channel numbers away from any neighboring networks
2. sens - sensitivity is very subjective and requires you to fiddle with it a lot
3. rts - setting this to auto helps
4. txpower - check your NIC to see what it's capable of, I've had good luck setting linksys/cisco NICs to 84mW